# "ytplayer is not defined"

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to use Youtube API and always get error "ytplayer is not defined".

I've copied the code in http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/chromeless_example_1.html to my .html file, hosted in my computer "ytplayer is not defined". I tried different code but again said "ytplayer is not defined".

What is the problem?

Comment: could you give me the URL of the page you are working on and I'll have a look. Make sure that ytplayer is set to something before you call the play function

Comment: the html file is hosted in my computer.

but there is no problem in here http://gkaans.org/dosya/video.html

Comment: it should be hosted on my computer :(

Answer (score 5):

From the [YouTube JavaScript Player API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html):

> Note: To test any of these calls, you
>   must have your file running on a
>   webserver, as the Flash player
>   restricts calls between local files
>   and the internet.

Answer (score 0):

how are you running the application?  if its in the air framework, check you haven't got transparency=true set in the configuration.  it won't load swf with transparency enabled.